# How was the faulty ShadowCash implementation of ring signatures repaired in February 2016?

Tags: ring-signatures, implementation, shadowcash

> The cryptocurrency *ShadowCash* uses traceable ring signature to anonymize the sender of a transaction. However, **these** were originally implemented **incorrectly**, resulting in a partial de-anonymization of *ShadowCash* from their first implementation until February 2016 by Monero Research Labs researcher, Shen Noether. <sup>[wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_signature#Crypto-currencies)</sup>

From the technical perspective, how was Shadowcash's implementation of ring signatures fixed which prevented the partial de-anonymization of it? What was the fix and by whom was it performed?

Comment: the question seems to imply that a fix could prevent the existing de-anonymization of the blockchain which it cannot. A fix can only prevent the same de-anonymization techniques to unravel blocks occurring after the alleged fix.

Comment: Who is downvoting this question? This isn't Reddit, downvote when something is off-topic or whatever.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is incorrect.

The original implementation of ring signatures is not thought to be faulty.

The original implementation of ring signatures is not from Shadowcash, but from Bytecoin. Shadowcash implemented their own version of it, buggily.

So Shen did not fix ring signatures, though he did find the fault in Shadowcash's reimplementation. I believe Shadowcash eventually fixed their bug after claiming this was FUD.

See https://shnoe.wordpress.com/2016/02/11/de-anonymizing-shadowcash-and-oz-coin/ for the details, and https://github.com/ShenNoether/Deanon for the deanonymization code.

Comment: I've added cite from wiki to clarify which says that ring signatures _were originally implemented incorrectly_. Is the information on wiki not correct, or I misunderstood it?

Comment: The wording on that link is ok, the "these" clearly refers to Shadowcash's. The Shadowcash reimplementation of ring signatures was originally buggy, but not the original implementation of ring signatures (as far as we know at this time), which was in Bytecoin.

Comment: As far as I know, the Shadowcash coders fixed it. I assume by changing the hash function used there, but I do not know for a fact. The question is still badly worded, since "the original implementation" can only be understood as Bytecoin's. Make it "Shadowcash's implementation" and it'd be clear.