# Is it easily provable by a third party that the key image used in a transaction is associated with the spent output without revealing the (P,I) pair?

Tags: security, transaction-data, key-image, auditing, transaction-key

What I'm getting at is I'd like to know how the Monero network can know that a key image used in a transaction is not either forged (probably an easy answer) or created from a different output owned by the same wallet (perhaps a more technical, but hopefully straightforward, answer).

The transaction private key, `x`, probably signs the ring and the key image, right?  My hunch is that the distinctive ring signature provides a way to check the math that `P` (the output public key) being spent is a ring member, and is also associated with `I`, the key image that's attached to the ring signature.

How does it work?  I don't understand how the verification works without revealing the actual tx pub key being spent.

I've been reading other SE questions and answers [here](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/2883/what-is-a-key-image), [here](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/2158/what-is-moneros-mechanism-for-defending-against-a-double-spend-attack?noredirect=1&lq=1), and [here](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/4015/is-making-a-key-image-public-equal-to-giving-the-monero-in-that-output-away).  I haven't found an answer expressed in the way I'd like to understand it.

Comment: See also this one: https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/4576/how-do-key-images-really-work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The signature verification algorithm will only return a "correct signature" result if `P` is equal to `x·G` (i.e. the real spent output's public key is derived from the output's secret spend key `x`) and if `I` is equal to `x·Hp(P)` (i.e. the key image I is derived from the output's secret spend key `x`).

If you can understand the algorithms on page 6 of [MRL-0003](https://lab.getmonero.org/pubs/MRL-0003.pdf), you will see that the `Li` elements check the public key and the `Ri` elements check the key image.

```
Signature algorithm:
--------------------
i ← 0
while i < numkeys do
  if i = s then
    k ← random Fq element
    Li ← k·G
    Ri ← k·Hp(Pi)
  else
    k1 ← random Fq element
    k2 ← random Fq element
    Li ← k1·Pi + k2·G
    Ri ← k1·I + k2·Hp(Pi)
    ci ← k1
    ri ← k2
  end if
  i ← i + 1
end while
h ← Hs(prefix + {Li} + {Ri})
cs ← h − ∑ci   (with i ≠ s)
rs ← k − x·cs
return (I, {ci}, {ri})


Verification algorithm:
-----------------------
i ← 0
while i < numkeys do
  L′i ← ci·Pi + ri·G
  R′i ← ri·Hp(Pi) + ci·I
  i ← i + 1
end while
h ← Hs(prefix + {L′i} + {R′i})
h ← h − ∑ci
return (h = 0 (mod q))
```

The verification algorithm will give a "correct signature" result when `∑ci` is equal to `Hs(prefix + {L′i} + {R′i})`. For this to be true, `{L'i}` must be equal to `{Li}` and `{R'i}` must be equal to `{Ri}`.

For the decoy keys (i.e. `i ≠ s`) it is obvious that `L'i = Li` and `R'i = Ri` as they are generated with identical formulas.

For the real key (i.e. `i = s`):

```
    L's = Ls
<=> cs·Ps + rs·G = k·G
<=> cs·Ps + (k - cs·x)·G = k·G
<=> cs·Ps + k·G - cs·x·G = k·G
<=> cs·Ps = cs·x·G

    R's = Rs
<=> rs·Hp(Ps) + cs·I = k·Hp(Ps)
<=> (k - cs·x)·Hp(Ps) + cs·I = k·Hp(Ps)
<=> k·Hp(Ps) - cs·x·Hp(Ps) + cs·I = k·Hp(Ps)
<=> cs·I = cs·x·Hp(Ps)
```

So for the signature to be valid, the signer has to know the secret key `x` so that `x·G = Ps` and `x·Hp(Ps) = I`.